# iPhone data connection types

Tags: iphone

Just curious — could anyone explain the exact meaning of all the connection type symbols in iPhone?

Let's see, **wifi** and **3G**, the fastest connection types, are quite clear, but how about the others: **E** is probably for [EDGE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced%5FData%5FRates%5Ffor%5FGSM%5FEvolution) (aka EGPRS), but what does the circle (**O**) mean? (2G something? [GPRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPRS)? Or is the latter a higher-level concept in mobile data transfer?) EDGE is presumably the better of these two? (In practice I haven't noticed great difference as both are much slower than 3G.)

Finally, how do [UMTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UMTS) or [W-CDMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W-CDMA%5F%28UMTS%29) fit in this picture? And if EDGE is a 3G technology too (as stated in Wikipedia), what kind of 3G technology exactly does iPhone's "3G" refer to? 
(Also, please correct me if there are more than the four types I could remember.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On GSM (All but Verizon/Sprint):

- 4G = LTE (or HSPA+ on AT&T)
- 3G = UTMS/HSDPA
- E = EDGE
- o = GPRS

On CDMA (Verizon or Sprint in the USA):

- 4G = LTE
- 3G = EV-DO
- E = no equivalent - not possible
- o = 1xRTT

Comment: Thanks for the authoritative reference! (To me it seems to be page *14* in the PDF.) Meaning of GPRS still isn't perfectly clear as Wikipedia says it's available in 2G *and* 3G systems http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Packet_Radio_Service — but I guess I'd need a degree in mobile telecommunication technology anyway to fully understand this multitude of standards. :-)

Comment: @Jonik - The Status Icons reference I looked at was on page 21. To be honest that was all I was looking for :)

Comment: I'm not totally sure what the phone is doing exactly when using GPRS, but I can tell you from experience that the circle means the phone has a data connection, but it's too slow to be worth using. :)

Answer (score 0):

The circle is GPRS, and UMTS or W-CDMA are technologies that make up 3G. Edge is not a 3G connection, it is a 2G connection.

Comment: Hmm - but Wikipedia says: "EDGE is considered a 3G radio technology and is part of ITU's 3G definition." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Data_Rates_for_GSM_Evolution

Comment: It may be in the ITU 3G definitions, but that Wikipedia entry reads like propaganda. EDGE is typically referred to as "2.5G" (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2.5G for another perspective) by everyone else and does not require the UMTS technology to work.