# What does a "o" symbol instead of "3G" or "E" mean?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone data connection types](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22279/iphone-data-connection-types)

I sometimes get a **"o"** icon instead of the "**3G**" or "**E**" icons when I loose my connection to the network. Why?

Could this be due to a jailbreak?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are connected to GPRS/1xRTT since other network connection types are not available.

### iOS 5.1 status icons

On GSM (All but Verizon):

- 3G = UTMS/HSDPA
- E = EDGE
- **o = GPRS**

On CDMA (Verizon):

- 3G = EV-DO
- E = no equivalent - not possible
- o = 1xRTT

([iPhone User Manual](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en/iphone_user_guide.pdf#page=12) on Page 12)

Comment: Please note: This answer [is pirated](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/22281/13414). Please give credit to @Diago for the original answer :)

Comment: That being the case, this question should probably be closed as a duplicate of that one... :)

Comment: @djacobson This isn't really an exact duplicate. This question is rather closely related. I once flagged such a question in a likewise case and the flag got rejected :(.

Answer (score 1):

It means you are using the slower GPRS connection. Probably because there's no 3G/EDGE connection or the signal strength for 3G/EDGE is very weak at your location.

Nothing to do with your jailbreaking.