# Comparing iPad mini data plans; Why choose AT&T, it has fewer countries and is more expensive?

Tags: ipad, cellular-carriers, cellular-data

I'm trying to choose between the various data plans for an iPad Mini.  [Based on this chart](http://www.apple.com/ipad/LTE/) it appears that the ATT model (A1454) only works in North/South America, while model A1455 is supported worldwide.

For this reason (limitation) I assumed the ATT plan would be least expensive per MB/Month, however it is the [most expensive](http://store.apple.com/us-hed/buy/home/shop_ipad/family/ipad_mini#) per month:

```
  ATT       250MB per month $14.99
  SPRINT    300MB per month $14.99  (better value)
  Verizon     1GB per month $20.00  (best value)
```

What is the value in the ATT network or related technology that I'm missing?

Finally, I've been told that GSM operates worldwide, are both these models [GSM or CDMA](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/22281/1337)?

Comment: The chart that you are looking for is for LTE (**4G**) only. Both models support GSM, and the A1455 also supports CDMA, check here: https://www.apple.com/ipad-mini/specs/. Also, both models would work worldwide on **3G** as they support UMTS/HSPA+/DC-HSDPA (850, 900, 1900, 2100 MHz).

Answer (score 1):

The value of any particular carrier is based on the performance of the carrier in the area you will use the device.

ie. My area has great AT&T coverage, Good Verizon coverage and horrible Sprint coverage.

You are also only comparing the cheapest tier. Prices change and one carrier may be cheaper than another at a different level of service.

Comment: What @drummin said, and if you already use AT&T then you'd probably want to stick with it.